# query for retrieving product(column) in mysql

Tags: mysql

say for an example
i have employee table with `id,name,salary`

```
id |name|salary
1  |raj |50.00
2  |raaj|60.00
3  |nera|555.55
```

i want to multiply the salary field `50*60*555.55=1666650.00`

```
salary
------
1666650.00
```

Comment: Can you please explain how do you want to get `1666650.00` from `50`, `60`, `555.55`?

Comment: do you want sum of salary column?

Comment: Please refine your question. The calculation to get to your wanted salary value is very unclear.

Comment: The *product* of the salaries? Really? What sense does it make?

Answer (score 2):

i think you want the sum of all salary column if you want

```
select sum(salary)as salary from employee
```

if you want product then it is

```
  select   round(EXP(SUM(LOG(salary))),2) as salary from employee
```

see the example for different rounding in mysql

```
  SELECT ROUND( 1 );   /* = 1 */
    SELECT ROUND( 1.4 ); /* = 1 */
    SELECT ROUND( 1.5 ); /* = 2 */

    SELECT ROUND( -1.4 ); /* = -1 */
    SELECT ROUND( -1.5 ); /* = -2 */

    SELECT ROUND( 1.4212, 1 ); /* = 1.4 */
    SELECT ROUND( 1.4512, 1 ); /* = 1.5 */
```

Comment: No, I need product of salary. There is no product(salary) so how can i query to retrieve the answer 50*60*555.55=1666650.00

Comment: It's not accurate . when i gave some integer values like 1,2,3,4 answer should be 24 but its showing 23.999999999999993 . Y not 24 ??

Comment: Normally salary won't be -ve. If there is some other column say values which contains some -ve values. Will this query results the correct answer with correct sign

Comment: @sabari i think you should not let the value to be inserted as negative from your front end.

Comment: I Want Query to handle -ve values too - @Dinup

Comment: @sabari i will write a query to handle negative number value but tell me first if you have -5 as negative salary then `-5 * anySalary` will be in negative or positive?

Comment: depends on anySalary sign. 
If anysalary is -ve then ans is +ve 
else ans is -ve

Comment: sorry cant help you anymore. search google and try your answer. you question is really unclear ` If anysalary is -ve then ans is +ve else ans is -ve ` i cannot understand a bit.

Comment: -5 * anysalary ; here If anysalary is -ve then ans is +ve else ans is -ve

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can try this-

```
select exp(sum(log(coalesce(salary,1)))) as d from employee
```

You can get more information on

http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/166184

Comment: This Query won't handle -ve value it seems..I want Query to handle -ve values too

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code in which @comb represents a constant that you initialize to 1 and for every row gets accumulated with its product to salary.

```
 SET @comb = 1;
    SELECT @comb:= @comb* salary
    FROM employee
```